Filter method is not accepted on SwiftUi
When I try to filter the results on recentMessages, it does not allow me and I get this error:

Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'Predicate<RecentMessage>' that does not accept a closure

This is the method I try to use:
func filterMessages(for userId: String) {
    self.filteredMessages = self.recentMessages.filter { $0.senderId == userId || $0.receiverId == userId }
}

This is RecentMessage:
struct RecentMessage: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id: String { documentId }
    let documentId: String
    let timestamp: Timestamp
    let senderId, receiverId, content : String
    init(documentId: String, data: [String : Any]) {
        self.documentId = documentId
        self.senderId = data["fromId"] as? String ?? ""
        self.receiverId = data["toId"] as? String ?? ""
        self.content = data["content"] as? String ?? ""
        self.timestamp = data["timestamp"] as? Timestamp ?? Timestamp(date: Date())
        }
    }

I tried this way. Then I don't get error but when I put a breakpoint here it does not hit this line:
return message.receiverId == userId || message.senderId == userId

func filterMessages(for userId: String) {
  self.filteredMessages = self.recentMessages.filter { (message: RecentMessage) -> Bool  in
            return message.receiverId == userId || message.senderId == userId
        }
    }

Edit: after posting this one, I added Dispatchqueue.main.async to before the filtering and it worked. Isn't it weird? Is there any line or variables here which is unnecessary or wrong? This is for messaging app . At the first run of the app, the user signs up then his details are saved to UserProfile struct then when he starts messaging his messages are saved to messages and recentMessages . And in conversationView i show filteredMessages from the MessagingService. Here is ConversationsView and MessagingService
import Firebase

struct ConversationsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var messagingService: MessagingService
    @EnvironmentObject var userProfileService: UserProfileService
    @EnvironmentObject var authService: AuthService
    @Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss
    @Binding var userId: String // Örnek olarak currentUserId
    @State private var conversations: [String] = []
    @State private var receiverNames: [String] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                conversationList
                    .navigationBarTitle("MESSAGES")
                    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .topBarLeading) {
                            backButton
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            messagingService.fetchRecentMessages()
        }
    }
    
    private var conversationList: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            ForEach(messagingService.chatUser, id: \.id) { user in
                HStack {
                    userImageView(for: user)
                    userMessagesView(for: user)
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func userImageView(for user: UserProfile) -> some View {
        Group {
            if let url = URL(string: user.profileImageUrl ?? "") {
                AsyncImage(url: url) { phase in
                    switch phase {
                    case .empty:
                        ProgressView()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 200)
                    case .success(let image):
                        image
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                    case .failure:
                        Image(systemName: "photo")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                    @unknown default:
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                }
                .cornerRadius(10)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func userMessagesView(for user: UserProfile) -> some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(user.name ?? "")
                    .font(.caption)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                Text(user.id ?? "")
            }
            ForEach(messagingService.filteredMessages.filter { $0.receiverId == user.id || $0.senderId == user.id }, id: \.documentId) { message in
                Text(message.content)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .background(Color.blue)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            //messagingService.filterMessages(for: user.id ?? "")
        }
    }
    
    private var backButton: some View {
        Button(action: {
            withAnimation(.snappy(duration: 2)) {
                dismiss()
            }
        }) {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                Text("Back")
            }
        }
    }
}

```import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import SwiftUI

class MessagingService: ObservableObject {
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    @ObservedObject var userProfileService = UserProfileService(authService: AuthService())
    @ObservedObject var authService = AuthService()
    @Published var messages: [ChatMessage] = []
    @Published var chatUser: [UserProfile] = []
    @Published var users = [ChatUser]()
    @Published var recentMessages: [RecentMessage] = []
    // Add a new published property to hold filtered messages
    @Published var filteredMessages: [RecentMessage] = []
    
    //        init(userProfileService: UserProfileService) {
    //            self.userProfileService = userProfileService
    //        }
    
    func sendMessage(_ message: Message) {
        let document = db.collection("messages")
            .document(message.senderId)
            .collection(message.receiverId)
            .document()
        
        let messageData = ["fromId": message.senderId, "toId": message.receiverId, "content": message.content, "timestamp": message.timestamp] as [String : Any]
        
        document.setData(messageData) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("ERROR SAVING MESSAGE INTO FIRESTORE \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            
        }
        
        let recipientMessageDocument = db.collection("messages")
            .document(message.receiverId)
            .collection(message.senderId)
            .document()
        
        recipientMessageDocument.setData(messageData) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("ERROR SAVING MESSAGE INTO FIRESTORE \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
        }
        
        
    }
    
    func persistRecentMessage(_ message: Message) {
        guard let uid = authService.user?.uid else {return}
        
        let document = db.collection("recent_messages")
            .document(uid)
            .collection("messages")
            .document(message.receiverId)
        
        let data = [
            "timestamp": message.timestamp,
            "content": message.content,
            "fromId": message.senderId,
            "toId": message.receiverId
        ] as [String : Any]
        
        document.setData(data) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("failed to save recent message: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
        }
        
        let recipientRecentMessageDocument = db.collection("recent_messages")
            .document(message.receiverId)
            .collection("messages")
            .document(message.senderId)
        
        recipientRecentMessageDocument.setData(data) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("failed to save recent message: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fetchMessages(_ toId: String) {
        guard let uid = authService.user?.uid else {return}
        db.collection("messages")
            .document(uid)
            .collection(toId)
            .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("FAILED TO LISTEM FOR MESSAGES: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
                
                querySnapshot?.documentChanges.forEach({ change in
                    if change.type == .added {
                        let data = change.document.data()
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let newMessage = ChatMessage(documentId: change.document.documentID, data: data)
                            self.messages.append(newMessage)
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        
    }
    
    func fetchRecentMessages() {
        self.filteredMessages.removeAll()
           guard let uid = authService.user?.uid else { return }
           db.collection("recent_messages")
               .document(uid)
               .collection("messages")
               .addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
                   if let error = error {
                       print(error.localizedDescription)
                       return
                   }

                   let group = DispatchGroup()
                   
                   querySnapshot?.documentChanges.forEach { change in
                       if change.type == .added {
                           let docId = change.document.documentID
                           
                           if !self.recentMessages.contains(where: { $0.documentId == docId }) {
                               let newMessage = RecentMessage(documentId: docId, data: change.document.data())
                               self.recentMessages.append(newMessage)
                               group.enter()
                               self.addReceiverNamesToMessages(for: uid, documentId: docId) {
                                   group.leave()
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
                   
                   group.notify(queue: .main) {
                       self.filterMessages(for: uid)
                       print("ALL PROFILES FETCHED")
                       print("\(self.filteredMessages)")
                   }
               }
       }
    
    
    func addReceiverNamesToMessages(for userId: String, documentId: String, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
            db.collection("recent_messages")
                .document(userId)
                .collection("messages")
                .document(documentId)
                .getDocument { documentSnapshot, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                        completion()
                        return
                    }

                    if let documentSnapshot = documentSnapshot, let data = documentSnapshot.data() {
                        if let senderId = data["fromId"] as? String, !self.chatUser.contains(where: { $0.id == userId }) {
                            self.userProfileService.fetchUserProfile(uid: senderId) { result in
                                switch result {
                                case .success(let profile):
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                        self.chatUser.append(profile)
                                    }
                                case .failure:
                                    break
                                }
                                completion()
                            }
                        } else {
                            completion()
                        }
                    } else {
                        completion()
                    }
                }
        }
    // Update filteredMessages based on the current recentMessages
       func updateFilteredMessages() {
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.filteredMessages = self.recentMessages
           }
       }

       // New function to filter messages for a specific user
       func filterMessages(for userId: String) {
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.filteredMessages = self.recentMessages.filter { $0.receiverId == userId || $0.senderId == userId }
           }
       }
    }


where did you use filterMessages function?

actually when i put a dot after $0. like this it doesn't even suggesting me the variables inside the RecentMessage struct.

I think there is a conflict here so that compiler cannot infer recentMessages or filterMessages. Mine works. You can try to minimize to a single struct RecentMessage with 2 arrays like above, then filterMessages is fine.

are you trying to use func filterMessages(...) in
a #Predicate<RecentMessage> or a FetchDescriptor<RecentMessage> or @Query
by any chance? If so edit your post and show this code.

shall i include whole(whole means a few functions) messaging service here for you guys to check?

Note, nesting ObservedObject is not a great idea.
Although it is possible, there are many posts on the resulting problems
on SO and the net. Also @ObservedObject is only meaningful in a View not
for use in other classes (eg MessagingService).

Normally you would have a custom View that takes the messages and the userID and SwiftUI will track those and automatically call body when either of them change. From there you call a computed var to do the filtering and pass it down to a child View, e.g.
struct FilterView: View {
    let userId: String
    let recentMessages: [Message]

    var filteredMessages: [Message] {
        recentMessages.filter { $0.senderId == userId || $0.receiverId == userId }
    }

    var body: View {
        ForEach(filteredMessages) { message in
        ...
    }
}

It's kind of like a chain, if FilterView is init with different userID or messages from last time, then body is called and in turn filterMessages. This the filtering only actually happens when necessary and everything stays up to date.

Yes i have a separate messages view that handles message logs. This is main messaging view which shows the message senders and a small preview of their messages
